# Pass JSON object to Python Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, json

I want to pass a JSON object of the form {key : value} having many elements to python script . 
I am able to send the JSON object via Ajax as i can see that in success in response variable in Ajax function.

I am using cgi.FieldStorage() to get POST data . I want to traverse the received JSON object elements and store the key and value in variables . Later , i want to use those variables in printing HTML through that Python Script . I don't know how to proceed and iterate .

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a `cgi.FieldStorage`, just simply read stdin:

```
import sys
import json

data = json.load(sys.stdin)
```

on the client side, you also have to convert your data manually into a json-string:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/city/cgi-bin/test1.py",
    type: "post",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify({'lat':30.5 , 'lon' : 4.5}),
    success: function(response){
        //window.location="http://mycity.parseapp.com/city/cgi-bin/test1.py"
        console.log(response.message);
        console.log(response.keys);
        console.log(response.data);

    }
});
```

Comment: i am passing data from Javascript to Python script using Ajax and Jquery . Doesn't it require cgi.FieldStorage() to get POST data in Python script ?

Comment: stdin is the way POST data gets into a cgi-script. `cgi.FieldStorage` only also reads from stdin. Try it ;-)

Comment: its showing internal server error . i am using ur code in python script . Also i want to print the content of 'data' in form of key,value pair in HTML . How can i do it ? 

print "<h1>" , json.dumps(data , indent= 2) , "<br>"

Comment: what is this internal server error; what is in the error log? are cgi-scripts working in general?

Comment: Here is my python script 
http://pastebin.com/vZY32Cpg
and here is my ajax code using jquery
http://pastebin.com/UAi0DNYD

These both are working . Now i want to store the key,value pair in python script and output them using HTML from the same python script . I am not able to traverse the JSON object and store them in python script .

Comment: No JSON object could be decoded                                                       
undefined 
undefined

Comment: Hey i am able to get the json object . Now i want to store key,value pair in variables and print them using HTML . This all in the same python script . How to proceed now ?